# Counting repetition of words in a list

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, count

I am trying to construct a program that if a user enters a name, it will return the number of people with that name. If they type 'most', it will return the name used the most. I tried writing the code below but this just gives me all the count for each of the words.

```
import re

data = ('Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Horace', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Doug', 'Misty', 'Wilma', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Bailey', 'Peggy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Paris', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty Mae', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Bart', 'Big Daddy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'LeeAnne', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Rowdy', 'Billy Bob', 'Ricky', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'EvaSue', 'Mark', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Rob', 'Betty Sue', 'SuelySue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr Jr', 'Billy Bob', 'Grady', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Louise', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jenny Jae', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'BJ', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Boris', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Pegs', 'Misty', 'Leslie', 'James', 'Melvin', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mary Beth', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'BethAnne', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Bett', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Raina', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mikey', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Louise Jr', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Horace', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Doug', 'Misty', 'Wilma', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Bailey', 'Peggy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Paris', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Misty Mae', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Bart', 'Big Daddy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'LeeAnne', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Rowdy', 'Billy Bob', 'Ricky', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'EvaSue', 'Mark', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Rob', 'Betty Sue', 'SuelySue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jesse Jr Jr', 'Billy Bob', 'Grady', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Louise', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Jenny Jae', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Jesse', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'BJ', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Boris', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Pegs', 'Misty', 'Leslie', 'James', 'Melvin', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mary Beth', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'BethAnne', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Bett', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Billy Bob', 'Raina', 'Betty Sue', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Mikey', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Betty Sue', 'Leroy', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue', 'Louise Jr', 'Billy Bob', 'Misty', 'Leroy', 'Leroy', 'Billy Bob', 'Billy Bob', 'Betty Sue')

print('''Welcome to the White Valley Name Counter. Enter a name, or "most" to see what name is the most used in this great city!''')

print()
keepgoing = 'y'

while keepgoing == 'y':
    search = input("What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? ")
    data_list = list(data)
    i_data = set(data_list)
    for i in i_data:
        print((i, data_list.count(i)))
    keepgoing = input('''Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? ''')
```

I want to make it so that my code will make an output like this:

```
Welcome to the White Valley Name Counter. Enter a name, or "most" to see what name is the most used in this great city!

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? john

There are 0 people named john

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? y

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? Betty Sue

There are 79 people named Betty Sue

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? y

What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? most

Billy Bob is most common. There are 93 of them

Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? n
```

Comment: from collections import Counter; data = Counter(data). This will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list count method to do this.

```
ls = [*names*]     #note this is a list!
while True:
    x = raw_input("What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? ")

if x != "most":
    print "There are %s people named %s" % (ls.count(x), x)
else:
    max_name = max(set(ls), key=ls.count)    #gets the most common name
    max_count = ls.count(max_name)
    print "There are %s people named %s" %(max_count, max_name)

y = raw_input("Want to search another name ('y' for yes)?")
if y == "n": break
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the loop and add condition for `most`.

```
while keepgoing == 'y':

    search = input("What name do you want to search for in White Valley database? ")

    data_list = list(data)

    print(data_list)

    print("There are {} people nammed {}".format(data_list.count(search),search))

    keepgoing = input('''Want to search another name ("y" for yes)? ''')
```

And use Counter, they really makes your life easier.